# Maintain auth session when POSTing from external site - Django

Tags: django, http-post, django-sessions, cross-site

I have a django app which receives data (a user ID) in a POST request and displays relevant content on screen. The app requires user auth before displaying the page with content.

The POST request comes from a form on a different site but the user is required to authenticate **every** time that a POST request is made. I've created a similar form within the site which doesn't require auth each time. Is it a standard thing for requests coming from an external site to need auth every time?